# How to allocate dynamic memory in a dynamic structure variable?

Tags: c

I want to allocate some memory to one of the members of a dynamic structure, dynamically. But I don't know what do I do and also, i don't know how to use them after allocating.

This is my code work :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct Sample_Structure {
        float *Number_ptr;    // This is the pointer to allocate some memory, dynamically.
        int Num1;
        int Num2;
    } *struct_ptr;

    struct_ptr = (struct Sample_Structure*) malloc (sizeof (struct Sample_Structure));
    if (!struct_ptr)
    {
        printf("An error occurred while allocating memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // I don't know what do I write here to allocate some memory to the pointer, "Number_ptr" in the structure

    printf("Enter your number 1 and 2 : ");
    scanf("%d%d", &struct_ptr->Num1, &struct_ptr->Num2);
    system("cls");

    printf("Your numbers are %d and %d\n", Struct_ptr->Num1, Struct_ptr->Num2);

    return 0;
  }
```

I wrote some comments for you to know where did I want to allocate some memory to the pointer of the structure, "Sample_Structure". Generally, can we do that? If yes, how?

Comment: struct_ptr->Number_ptr = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));

Comment: Drop the cast, don't guess on type.  `struct_ptr->Number_ptr =  malloc(sizeof *(struct_ptr->Number_ptr) * Number_desired);`.  Notice no type in this code.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you want to allocate memory for 10 floats for `Number_ptr`:

```
struct_ptr->Number_ptr = malloc( sizeof(float) * 10 );
```

---

Correction:

Change this line

```
printf("Your numbers are %d and %d\n", Struct_ptr->Num1, Struct_ptr->Num2);
                                       ^                 ^
```

to

```
printf("Your numbers are %d and %d\n", struct_ptr->Num1, struct_ptr->Num2);
```

And, you're leaking memory. You need to deallocate memory using `free()` after use. Make sure for every allocation e.g. `malloc()`, there is corresponding deallocation e.g. `free()`.

Also, validate if the memory is allocated or not.

Here's a small example for your reference ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/Pbw-dm)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX 10

typedef struct S
{
    int* ilist;
} S;

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.ilist = malloc( MAX * sizeof(*s.ilist) );     // allocation
    if ( s.ilist == NULL )
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // An assertion may also be used like this (Header: <assert.h>):
    // assert( s.ilist != NULL );

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i )
    {
        s.ilist[i] = i + 1;                         // store elements
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i )
    {
        printf("%d ", s.ilist[i]);                  // read elements
    }

    free( s.ilist );                                // deallocation
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: @AmirMohsenGhasemi: Simply dereference it according to its capacity i.e. number of elements. If there are multiple elements, use a loop. BTW, why is it a pointer? What is your use-case?

Comment: You allocated an array of float variables to the pointer, "Number_ptr". Now I want to use seventh variable of the dynamic array to print or input. What do I do?

Comment: @AmirMohsenGhasemi: Just like you use an array subscript operator e.g. `struct_ptr->Number_ptr[index]`.

Comment: @AmirMohsenGhasemi: I've updated my answer with an example and some other points. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can allocate memory the for it , the same way you allocated for `*struct_ptr`
like this

`struct_ptr->Number_ptr = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));`.

and when you want to scan data for it you shouldn't use `&` for it:

`scanf("%d%d%f", &struct_ptr->Num1, &struct_ptr->Num2, struct_ptr->Number_ptr);`

and in printf you should use `*` for it:

`printf("Your numbers are %d and %d\nand %f\n", struct_ptr->Num1, struct_ptr->Num2, *struct_ptr->Number_ptr);`

also you should this capital `S` to lowercase letter in this printf:

`printf("Your numbers are %d and %d\n", struct_ptr->Num1, struct_ptr->Num2);`

also note that you don't need to **cast** for `malloc` and it's not good to that , unless you're using `c++` compiler.

```
 int main()
 {
struct Sample_Structure {
     float* Number_ptr;    
     int Num1;
     int Num2;
 } *struct_ptr;

     struct_ptr = (struct Sample_Structure *)malloc(sizeof(struct Sample_Structure));
     if (!struct_ptr)
     {
         printf("An error occurred while allocating memory.\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     struct_ptr->Number_ptr = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));
     printf("Enter your number 1 and 2 : ");
     scanf("%d%d%f", &struct_ptr->Num1, &struct_ptr->Num2, struct_ptr->Number_ptr);
     system("cls");

     printf("Your numbers are %d and %d\nand %f\n", struct_ptr->Num1, struct_ptr->Num2, *struct_ptr->Number_ptr);

     return 0;
 }
```